# Class not found"PHPMailer"

Tags: php, runtime-error

I have this error in a project which says

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Classes\Email" not found in C:\Users\Elvyn D. Medina\Downloads\AppSalon_PHP_MVC_JS_SASS\AppSalon_PHP_MVC_JS_SASS\controllers\LoginController.php:54
```

but I have the class inherited correctly, I already installed the component and also updated composer, I no longer find what to do if someone can give me a hand I will be infinitely grateful.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AQ1n.png)

Comment: What about caller code?

Comment: Fixed problem: I was in the namespace, the folder was placed in uppercase while the path was in lowercase so it wouldn't find the mailer.